# Cloudinary upload image not working (react native and nodes

Tags: node.js, react-native, cloudinary, react-native-image-picker

I am trying to upload an image from my react native app to the nodejs and to the cloudinary cloud, but its not working for me. Thats my react-native code:

```
const App = () => {
  const [profileImageSource ,setProfileImageSource] = useState(require('./images/profilePic.png'));
  const [imageData, setImageData] = useState("");
  const [okay, setOkay] = useState(false);

  const config = {
    withCredentials: true,
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/',
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  };
  const handleProfileImage = () => {
      const options = {
        title: 'Select photo',
        base64: true
      };

      ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (res) => {
        if(res.didCancel){
        }
        else if(res.error){
        }
        else{
          const image = {data: res.data};

          axios
          .post('/clients/upload-image', {
            data: JSON.stringify({image})
          },
          config
        )
          .then((res) => console.log("ok"))
          .catch((err) => alert(err));
        }
      })
    }
```

And that's my nodesjs code:

```
require('dotenv').config();

const cloudinary = require('cloudinary').v2;

//Cloudinary configurations
cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
    api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
    api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET
});

app.post('/clients/upload-image', (req, res) => {
    const imageStr = req.body.data;
    const uploadedResponse = 
        cloudinary
        .uploader
        .upload(imageStr, {
            upload_preset: 'user',
        })
        .then((uploadedResponse) => console.log(uploadedResponse))
        .catch((err) => console.log("error"));
}
```

Where am I wrong? I keep getting errors and the pictures are not uploaded to the cloudinary

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the error message you've received?
Also, can you confirm that `imageStr` (aka `req.body.data`) is received correctly in the backend? (maybe print it before uploading?)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple for File uploading and using **formidable** as your bodyParser it will make your life easy using formidable, same might vouch for multer now that comes down to preference

**So firstly I would advise that in your client you also use JavaScript FormData(built-in lib)**

- So how you would handle things when time to send picture to server is like this below:

```
const uploadPicture = ()=>{

    const data = new FormData();
    
    data.append('image', file)// So 'image' is the key and **file** now this is the file uploaded in user that you have in state
    
    axios.post(url, data).then(res=>{
        
         console.log(res)
    
    }).catch(err=>{

        console.log(err)

    })

}
```

**Now how handle things is back-end**

- Firstly install `npm i formidable` or `yarn add formidable`
- Once that is done you ready to go.

```
const cloudinary = require('cloudinary').v2;
const Formidable = require('formidable');

cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
    api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
    api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET
});

router.post('/api/upload', (req, res)=>{

    const form = new Formidable.IncomingForm();//Here you initialze your formidable instance
    form.parse(req, (error, fields, files)=>{
      
       const {image} = files //So due to in our request we sent a **file** which is an image then formidable parsed that request and placed file received from client in **files** that you see in callback function so now we de-structure it by key that we set in client

        cloudinary.uploader.upload(image.path, {folder:'here you can specify folder you want'}, (err, results)=>{

            if (err) return console.log(err)
            const image_url = results.secure_url
        }) 

    })

})
```

- Now like this you uploaded your image

**If this did not make sense to you: Here is a shameless plug**

- Go checkout my channel on YouTube I have covered how to work with cloudinary
- Link: https://youtu.be/mlu-tbr2uUk